# Correct way of erasing a linked list

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, memory-management

Suppose, I have a singly linked list and its basic building block is,

```
struct Node {
  Data d;
  Node *pNext;
  // methods
  ~Node();
};
```

The head of the linked list is stored as,

```
Node *m_Head; // member of some class
```

When, I am done with the list, I will clean it by deleting each node as,

```
void Erase()
{
  Node *pIter, *pTemp = m_Head;
  while((pIter = pTemp) != 0)
  {
    pTemp = pIter->pNext;
    delete pIter;
    pIter = pTemp;
  }
}
```

I thought, if I can simplify this. So I came up with an idea where I can clean this whole linked list with just a single instruction !

```
delete m_Head;
```

and destructor will look like:

```
Node::~Node() { delete this->pNext; }
```

Here my concern is, will it cause **recursion** (implicitly due to `delete`) ? If yes, then it's definitely a concern for bigger linked lists. Will compiler be able to help in any way for optimizing that ?

[Note: Not using any library facility like `std::list` or other.]

Comment: note that if you chose the later [using delete], you will have to set `node->pNext = NULL;` before deleting it [when modifying the list, not destroying it], otherwise you will lose the tail of this sublist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Of course: Only do this for learning purposes or when you are sure that your own List is really better for your use case*

---

It depends. Possibly your compiler will detect a [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion) and emit code that is conceptually equivalent to using a loop.

If not, then yes, it will recurse. Usually, some thousands of recursions should be possible on commodity boxes, if stack pressure is small (like in your case). However, there is no guarantee, and indeed, for really large lists, this can be a problem.

Also, I think that recursion is indeed not entirely appropriate for the concept of sibling nodes. A node hierarchy, like with [quadtrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), cries for recursion, but I have a not so good time thinking in recursion (which forms a call *hierarchy*) when the list-concept is about *sibling*-nodes.

You may also consider the manual loop as a easy-to-achieve optimization over the recursion that will make your code more robust in a guaranteed way.

Btw, you <s>could also</s> *should* rip out the deletion of nodes into a holder class:

```
class List {
public:
    ~List() {
        for-each-node
            delete-node
    }

private:
    class Node {
        Node *node_;
        ...
    };
    ...
};
```

This is basically how the standard library's list is usually implemented. It makes the whole implementation easier to achieve and conceptually more correct (Nodes don't *own* their sibling logically)

Comment: AFAIK, the destruction of the `Data` member (and `Node`'s baseclass(es)) happen *at the end* of the `Node` destructor call, which makes it not tail recursive at all (unless all those are no-ops and optimized away).

Answer (score 3):

I think the question that you have to ask is, does each `Node` in the list *own* its `pNext` `Node`? If not, then it has no business deleting its `pNext` node in its destructor.

In most linked list implementations all the nodes are owned by the list, a node doesn't own all the nodes after it in the list. It makes more sense to keep the nodes as dumb (POD-structs) and let all of the logic reside in the list.

It's definitely a design "smell" that your node has a destructor but no copy constructor or copy assignment operator. I think this approach will cause more complexity when you come to code implementing insert, splice and erase single element functions as you will have to manually manage the `pNext` pointers in any case to avoid unintentional destruction of the entire tail of a list.

Comment: It seems natural in a `cons` list for a Node to own those which come after it, as the definition is `List a = Empty | Cons a List`. I agree that it requires careful manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Most compiler do [tail call elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) in default setting. Some smarter one can convert non-tail calls to tail calls.

So, this method okay as long as you have some optimization turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Raw pointers ? Manual calls to `delete` ?

Why not, simply:

```
struct Node {
  Data d;
  std::unique_ptr<Node> next;
};
```

Then you don't even have to worry about memory management at all, it's automatic!

Comment: Actually, this creates recursion, but will this prevent stackoverflow?  This was the main concern in the question.

Comment: @stefaanv: Open subject. It depends on the compiler and the standard library implementation, my hope is it would be, but that's guess work. I don't know if the standard promises a minimal recursion depth, I would not be surprised if it didn't concern itself with this.